# Returning a list of dictionaries by iterating over given data

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

So let's say I've a list of students and there is a dictionary containing some data for each student as given below :

```
students= [{'student_name': 'name1', 
          'regNO': '12',
          },{'student_name': 'name2', 
          'regNO': '13',
          },{'student_name': 'name3', 
          'regNO': '14',
          }
         ]
```

So based on the above data I want to return another list of dictionaries containing data for each student,

I wrote the following code :

```
res_dict = {}
res_list = []

    for student in students:
        res_dict['name']=student['student_name']
        res_list.append(res_dict)

print(res_list)
```

I was hoping that in the output, for each student , there would be a dictionary with key being 'name' and value being the student name taken from 'students' list. I expected it to be as follows :

```
[{'name': 'name1'}, {'name': 'name2'}, {'name': 'name3'}]
```

But the output turned out to be this :

```
[{'name': 'name3'}, {'name': 'name3'}, {'name': 'name3'}]
```

Can anyone help me identify the issue in my code ?

Answer (score 4):

The better way to get the desired result is via using *list comprehension* expression as:

```
[{'name': student['student_name']} for student in students]
```

---

The issue with your code is you are updating the values in same reference of the `dict` object and appending the same object again to the list. Change your code to:

```
for student in students:
    res_dict = {}  # Create new `dict` object
    res_dict['name'] = student['student_name']
    res_list.append(res_dict)
```

OR, you may just do:

```
for student in students:
    res_list.append({'name': student['student_name']})
```

Comment: @CodePlorer: But the part that you just mentioned is no where mentioned in the OP. I guess you should be able to modify the example I mentioned for multiple keys in nested dict. In case of further issues, please create new questions

Comment: But this works fine if there is a single key, I want it to return a list where there is a single dictionary for each student having multiple key value pairs : res_list.append({'name': student['student_name']})
    res_list.append({'register':student['regNO']})  returns something as follows : [{'name': 'name1'}, {'register': '12'}, {'name': 'name2'}, {'register': '13'}, {'name': 'name3'}, {'register': '14'}] Though I want the output as follows :   [{'name': 'name1', 'register': '12'}, {'name': 'name2', 'register': '13'}, {'name': 'name3', 'register': '14'}]

Comment: @CodePlorer Update the dict in my code snippet with `{'name': student['student_name'], 'register': student['regNO']}`

Answer (score 1):

The subtle concept of list is that it does not copy the item that you append to it.Instead of that it just stores the pointer to the newly added object via append,similar to pointer arrays in c.So when you try `print(res_dict)`,it will give you the the result like this `[{'name': 'name3'}, {'name': 'name3'}, {'name': 'name3'}]`.But when you append this to the list,all the items in the list point to the same object.You can verify this by this small fragment of code

```
for i in res_list:
    print(id(i))
```

You will find the same memory address for all the list elements.
But when you take a copy of the dictionary with the help of d.copy() and append that to the res_list,you can see that all the list objects are pointing to different objects by the same technique using id(i) and for loop as shown above.
So finally the corrected code would be

```
students= [{'student_name': 'name1', 
          'regNO': '12',
          },{'student_name': 'name2', 
          'regNO': '13',
          },{'student_name': 'name3', 
          'regNO': '14',
          }
         ]
res_dict = {}
res_list = []

    for student in students:
        res_dict['name']=student['student_name']
        res_list.append(res_dict.copy())

print(res_list)
```

Using list comprehension would always expose the contents to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic reference issue. In other words you are appending the reference to the same dict object. Thus, when you change the name value on it, for all times it shows up in the list it will reflect its new value. Instead, create a new dict for each iteration and append that :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it.

```
n_list = [{'name':i['student_name']} for i in students]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset `res_dict = {}` to an empty dict within your loop for each new entry.